# How to filter in kotlin using predicates

Tags: kotlin, filter, predicate

What i'm trying to achieve is using a filter function with dynamic predicates.
What I did so far is creating a function that choose the best predicate:

```
fun buildDatePredicate(dateFrom: LocalDate?, dateTo: LocalDate?): Predicate<MyClass> {
    if (dateFrom != null && dateTo == null) {
        return Predicate { myItem -> myItem.date.isAfter(dateFrom) }
    }
    if (dateTo != null && dateFrom == null) {
        return Predicate { myItem -> myItem.date.isBefore(dateTo) }
    }
    if (dateTo != null && dateFrom != null) {
        return Predicate { myItem ->
            myItem.date.isBefore(dateTo) && myItem.date.isAfter(dateFrom)
        }
    }

    return Predicate { true }
}
```

And then I tried to use filter on my list using that Predicate

```
myList.filter { buildDatePredicate(fromDate.toLocalDate(),toDate.toLocalDate()) }
```

But it does not works due to

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Boolean
Found:
Predicate<MyClass>
```

Is it possible to achieve what i'm trying to do?

Thanks

Comment: The main issue in this code is `filter { … }`: **the braces (curly brackets) define a lambda**. `filter` expects a function returning a boolean, but the lambda in code returns a Predicate, hence the error message. So the simplest way to fix it is **replace the braces with parens (round brackets)** — as per marstran's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution is to just call the `test`-method on the predicate:

```
myList.filter { 
    val pred = buildDatePredicate(fromDate.toLocalDate(), toDate.toLocalDate())
    pred.test(it)
}
```

But a more idiomatic solution in Kotlin is to not use `java.util.function.Predicate`, but rather a function of type `(MyClass) -> Boolean`. Then you can just pass the result of `buildDatePredicate` directly to the filter function. Like this:

```
fun buildDatePredicate(dateFrom: LocalDate?, dateTo: LocalDate?): (MyClass) -> Boolean {
    if (dateFrom != null && dateTo == null) {
        return { myItem -> myItem.date.isAfter(dateFrom) }
    }
    if (dateTo != null && dateFrom == null) {
        return { myItem -> myItem.date.isBefore(dateTo) }
    }
    if (dateTo != null && dateFrom != null) {
        return { myItem ->
            myItem.date.isBefore(dateTo) && myItem.date.isAfter(dateFrom)
        }
    }

    return { true }
}
```

And then call it with:

```
myList.filter(buildDatePredicate(fromDate.toLocalDate(), toDate.toLocalDate()))
```